# Unable to get narrator to let go on Nokia Lumia 520?

Tags: lumia-520, narrator

I have a Nokia Lumia 520 phone with Windows 8.1 upgrade. tried holding the Volume Up button for three seconds and simultaneously pressing the Start button as suggested, but the narrator will not let go, therefore I cannot access the setting to disable it! Now what!

Comment: Have you tried rebooting your phone?

Comment: I am taking it in to the ATT store today to see if they can help me.

Answer (score 2):

I went to the ATT store here in town. The representative there searched for an alternative solution for me. He was able to hold down the upper part of the volume button for 3 seconds and then double tap on the windows symbol on the phone, but not simultaneously. And it worked!

Comment: Since your problem is solved, why don't you mark your reply as an answer. It may help others. Else your question will still be marked as unanswered.